# JSON Error with Async.parallel

Tags: json, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using async.parallel to handle data and then I'll pass that collected data to my view.

However in the function, I get given JSON, but I can't use its fields.

```
async.parallel(jsearch, function(err, results) {

                console.log(results);
                console.log(results[0]);

                res.render('t.ejs', {
                    user : req.user, 
                    board : collected,
                    images : results
                });
});
```

console.log(results) returns the JSON

```
[ [ { _id: 565779c91dd21c0014d2bb21,
      created_on: Thu Nov 26 2015 21:29:45 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      like_count: 1,
      path: 'uploads/73fb95126e626af139c094c167753d9b',
      author: '246519777',
      __v: 0,
      likers: [] } ],
  [ { _id: 565b818b3f5aa8740334967d,
      created_on: Sun Nov 29 2015 22:51:55 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      like_count: 36,
      path: 'uploads/27ef8a8ec19929c6000d47e3943710da',
      author: '246519777',
      __v: 0,
      likers: [] } ],
  [ { _id: 565b818b3f5aa8740334967d,
      created_on: Sun Nov 29 2015 22:51:55 GMT+0000 (GMT),
      like_count: 36,
      path: 'uploads/27ef8a8ec19929c6000d47e3943710da',
      author: '246519777',
      __v: 0,
      likers: [] } ] ]
```

console.log(results[0]) returns the first item in that json

```
[ { _id: 565779c91dd21c0014d2bb21,
    created_on: Thu Nov 26 2015 21:29:45 GMT+0000 (GMT),
    like_count: 1,
    path: 'uploads/73fb95126e626af139c094c167753d9b',
    author: '246519777',
    __v: 0,
    likers: [] } ]
```

console.log(results[0].path) returns undefined.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a key on the array, not the object. Try `results[0][0].path` instead.

Comment: I've never encountered this before. How do I cycle through this? `results[0][i]` or `results[i][i]`

Comment: I cracked it, it's `results[i][0]`, just not sure why.

Comment: The format of the JSON response you're receiving is a bit weird because the inner arrays are extraneous -they will only ever have one item in them. So, iterating through the results with `results[i]` will always yield an array with a single object in it: `[{key: val}]`. Think of it as `var array = results[i]` and then you're simply accessing the first item of that array: `array[0]`.